# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSString' in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sigabrt

I am trying to pull articles from my database in firebase, but am getting a SIGABRT error in the let author part of this function, what is wrong?

```
func getAllArticles(handler: @escaping (_ articles: [Article])-> ()){

        var articleArray = [Article]()
        REF_ARTICLES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (articleMessageSnapshot) in
            guard let articleMessageSnapshot = articleMessageSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

            for article in articleMessageSnapshot {

                let content = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as! String
                let author = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "author").value as! String
                let twitterHandle = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "twitterHandle").value as! String
                let articleTitle = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "articleTitle").value as! String

                let article = Article(content: content, author: author, twitterHandle: twitterHandle, ArticleTitle: articleTitle)
                articleArray.append(article)
            }
            handler(articleArray)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing about Firebase, but from what you have posted, I don't think that is your problem.

This code `article.childSnapshot(forPath: "author").value` is returning `NSNull` meaning it found no values to match your criteria. The code `as! String` is literally saying to crash if the value is not a `String`. Since `NSNull` is not `String` you get the crash.

One solution:

```
let author = article.childSnapshot(forPath: "author").value as? String ?? "No Author"
```

Any maybe do that with all the lines. Also read about [Swift optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) and Forced Unwrapping.

Comment: the weird thing was in the the terminal it would show author as the correct value from the database

Comment: this worked for me when Xcode reminded me about optional chaining 